# change branch without passing uncommitted changes

Tags: git, switch-statement, git-checkout

I am in my branch **DEV**, I modify the file **A.txt**, when I do:

```
git checkout master
```

instead of denying me the `git checkout` and proposing to do a `git stash`, he passes my uncommitted changes

like this :

```
(DEV) $ git checkout master
M A.txt
(master) $ git status
modified A.txt
```

This is a recent problem that my colleague also has, what is it due to ?
I did not have this problem before ..

Thank you

Comment: This is how [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt) always worked.

Comment: Since you have no other A.txt in the master branch, git will encounter no problem switching to master branch.

Comment: Why is it a problem for you?

Comment: before I had the same thing as @florieger, which seems to be the normal behavior.
That's why now that Git's behavior is changing for me, it seems like a problem.

Answer (score 2):

After several tests I finally understood the real functioning of GIT.

It passes my changes as long as the're not committed, but once I commit, modifications doesn't pass.

From there (after a first commit), if I make changes on these same files and I try to change branch, GIT doesn't allow me and advises me to do a Stash.

So I covered all possible cases by my tests, thank you for your answers that helped me a lot to find the solution to my problem (which was to better understand the operation of GIT).

Answer (score 1):

I can only reproduce this if the branches point to the same commit.
In your scenario `DEV` and `master`.

Otherwise I get a message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Tests/ACInteractorTests/InteractorErrorTests.swift
    Tests/ACInteractorTests/LazyInteractorTests.swift
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
```

It looks like a convenience feature to me that git is not complaining as long as your new branch is still pointing to the same commit as your old branch.

Note: My git GUI client, Tower for Mac, always complains.

Comment: I had exactly the same thing as you, which seems to be the normal behavior.
Now I do not have this error anymore, it passes my uncommitted changes without error ...

Comment: @IkbelBmmi As I said before, the error is only shown when the old and new branch do *not* point at the same commit.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in the [documentation of `git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt):

> **git checkout `<branch>`**
>
> To prepare for working on `<branch>`, switch to it by updating the index and the files in the working tree, and by pointing `HEAD` at the branch. Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that they can be committed to the `<branch>`.

The checkout fails if the local changes cannot be successfully applied on the corresponding files checked out from the specified branch.